# Problem using Windows Installer for Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: installation

Once the installer begins to download Ubuntu an error occurs.

> An error occured
>   Cannot download the meta link and therefor the ISO
>   For more information please see the log file:
>   c:\users..yadi yadi...\wubi-12.04-rev269.log

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Download the ISO from this [page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Place it in the same directory as wubi.exe and then execute wubi.exe.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check the md5 of your iso if there is a problem download another one again and check its md5 then run **Wubi.exe** from the same directory you have the downlaoded iso